# Update with select and cases 'when/then'

Tags: mysql

When I try to execute this:

```
update YUmowa_Kontrahent  set YUK_Typ_Umowy=  'WS'
where YUK_IdObiekt in (select YO_Id,
sum(isnull(YROB_WZ_Woda,0))as woda,
sum(isnull(YROB_WZ_Scieki,0))as scieki ,
case 
    when sum(isnull(YROB_WZ_Woda,0))> 0 and sum(isnull(YROB_WZ_Scieki,0))>0 Then 'WS'
    end WS

    from YObiekt 
join YRozliczenie_Obiekt on YO_Id=YROB_IdObiekt
group by YO_Id)
```

I recieve:

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 45 Only one expression can be
>   specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with
>   EXISTS.

I need to update TYP UMOWY= 'WS' ON DBO.YUMOWA_KONTRAHENT which after sum records of 'WODA' & 'SCIEKI' >0
i specified in sub-query unique ID'S so???

Comment: mysql != sql-server

Comment: How to use [IN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE YUmowa_Kontrahent  
SET YUK_Typ_Umowy = 'WS'
WHERE YUK_IdObiekt IN (
    SELECT YO_Id
    FROM YObiekt 
        JOIN YRozliczenie_Obiekt ON YO_Id = YROB_IdObiekt
    GROUP BY YO_Id
    HAVING sum(isnull(YROB_WZ_Woda,0)) > 0 AND sum(isnull(YROB_WZ_Scieki,0)) > 0
)
```

The subquery in your query is wrong:

1. If you use some statement except `EXISTS`, you have to specify only
   one expression in the select list (as you could read in the error
   message).
2. Your subquery returns all `YO_Id` rather than return only that meet
       the condition `sum(isnull(YROB_WZ_Woda,0)) > 0 AND sum(isnull(YROB_WZ_Scieki,0)) > 0`
3. Of course, I don't know the structure of your tables, but it seems
   you don't need to join two tables in subquery but use only the table
   with fields `YROB_WZ_Scieki` and `YROB_WZ_Woda` to get IDs.

Comment: Add some explanation

Answer (score 0):

Your `select` is wrong because you can't use `in` with on the left 1 parameter and on the right 3 parameters:

```
select *
from table
where a in (select a, b, c from table2)
```

Instead you should use: `where a in (select a from table2)`